# Pandas replace front-end duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with many columns that have sequences of identical values. From each sequence of "N" identical values, I need to replace the first "N-1" values with "NaN" and keep the last value. For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'date': ['2019-01-01 00:00:00','2019-01-01 01:00:00','2019-01-01 02:00:00', '2019-01-01 03:00:00',
         '2019-09-01 02:00:00','2019-09-01 03:00:00','2019-09-01 04:00:00', '2019-09-01 05:00:00'],
'ColumnX': [10,10,10,10,11,10,10,12],    
})
```

I need to replace the first three values of 'ColumnX' with 'NaN' and keep only the last "10" value. After processing, the column should look like:

```
'value': [na,na,na,10,11,10,10,12]
```

Any sequence of identical values past the first non-identical value (i.e., "11" in this example) should be ignored in this processing.

What is the best way to do this for a large dataframe with many numeric columns?

Comment: There are  2 '10's as well, would you not like to replace the first 10 by NaN like this [na,na,na,10,11,na,10,12] ? Or is it because you have already encountered 10 before ?

Comment: Why is the 5th 10 not removed? `[na,na,na,10,11,na,10,12]`

Comment: The objective is to remove the all but the last of the front-end duplicates only (not any duplicates that appear later on in the time series).

Answer (score 0):

We can try with `diff` + `duplicated` then `mask` the result

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

m = df.assign(key = df['date'].diff().ne('01:00:00').cumsum()).duplicated(['key','ColumnX'],keep='last')
df['ColumnX'].mask(m,inplace=True)
df
Out[186]: 
                 date  ColumnX
0 2019-01-01 00:00:00      NaN
1 2019-01-01 01:00:00      NaN
2 2019-01-01 02:00:00      NaN
3 2019-01-01 03:00:00     10.0
4 2019-09-01 02:00:00     11.0
5 2019-09-01 03:00:00      NaN
6 2019-09-01 04:00:00     10.0
7 2019-09-01 05:00:00     12.0
```